# How can I change the background color of the body in index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm new to Reactjs! I did some researches in google on how to change the background color of the body in index.html but nothing work. I have tried to use `<style>` tag in the `<head>` tag and I have also tried to create new `style.css` file in `public` folder and linked it to `index.html` but it changed nothing!

here is how I linked style.css to index.html
`<link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Please help! Thank before hand

Update! When I refreshed the page the background color did change but only in around 0.001s then It went back to white.

Comment: show the content of style.css, pls

Comment: it has only `body {background-color: yellow;}`

Comment: does the css code show up if you inspect the body element? If not it might just be a problem with your css-integration.
Does your console throw any errors?

Comment: Everything is correct! It means there is a problem with the css file connection path. In the browser object inspector or in the dom structure of the site, do you see this css file? (in the head tag)

Comment: The console doesn't throw any errors! also the `<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` showed up in the head tag when I inspected.

Comment: Also When I refresh the page the color does show up but only around 0.001s then it goes back to white.

Comment: now click on the body tag in the dom structure, and see if there are any other rules in the object inspector that can also set the color to the body of the site, or with the `!important` parameter.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time! it works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inline CSS you can try :

```
<body style="background-color:yellow;">
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <p>We have developed more than 10 products till now.</p>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.css`, add:

```css
body {
  background-color: 'blue';
}
```